# Confusion in Clairaut's theorem.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

By solving the following expression by chain rule:

$$\dfrac{d}{d[f(s)]}    \left(  \dfrac{d[f(s)]}{ds}   \right)
= \dfrac{d[f'(s)]}{d[f(s)]}
=\dfrac{d[f'(s)]}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{d[f(s)]}  
=\dfrac{f''(s)}{f'(s)} $$

Now by solving by Clairaut's theorem:

$$
\dfrac{d}{d[f(s)]}    \left(  \dfrac{d[f(s)]}{ds}   \right)
=\dfrac{d}{ds} \left(  \dfrac{d[f(s)]}{d[f(s)]}  \right)
=\dfrac{d(1)}{ds}=0
$$

Why is this contradiction? What am I missing?

Comment: What is $[\cdot]$?

Comment: Any arbitrary function of $s$

Comment: I'm not asking about $f$ but about $[\cdot]$.

Comment: @Vim Maybe just braces?

Comment: Yes just braces so that $d$ and $f$ doesn't get mixed up

Comment: @TheDeadLegend this looks weird... I'd taken it for the floor function.

Comment: What is $\frac{d}{d[f(s)]}$ ?

Comment: Differentiation w.r.t. $f(s)$

Comment: Well I don't think you can just interchange $d/df(s)$ and $d/ds$. Let's just look at the example $f(s)=s^2,s>0$, then $$\frac{d}{d (s^2)}\frac{d(s^2)}{ ds} =\frac{d(2s)}{d (s^2)}=\frac1s  $$ where as $$\frac{d}{ ds}\frac{d(s^2)}{ d(s^2)} = \frac {d(1)}{ds} = 0$$

Comment: Why is Clairaut's theorem not applicable here?

Comment: @Vim: I understand. But please answer my final question.

Comment: I have never heard of such a theorem and I just searched the relevant wikipedia pages and found noun of them seems to be what you were using here. Anyway, what you were using in the second equation is simply wrong; perhaps you were misinterpretting a theorem and using it incorrectly.

Comment: Search the following wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: Clairaut's theorem is for *partial* derivatives. You have total derivatives in your expression.

Comment: What does "differentiation w.r.t. $f(s)$" mean? When I took calculus, we only learned differentiation with respect to a variable.

Comment: Isn't $$\frac d{d[f(s)]}\frac{d[f(s)]}{ds}=\frac d{ds}$$ by the chain rule?

Comment: @joe You say $\frac{d}{d[f(s)]}$ is differentiation with respect to $f(s)$ but what does it mean? Can you define it? If it cannot be defined, it cannot lead to any sound result.

Comment: @Joe I know where your confusion is: $s$ and $f(s)$ aren't independent so you cannot just treat them as independent $x_i,x_j$ as in Clairaut's theorem.

Comment: @Vim: Thanks..............